# CSS Dropdown Menu Changes div Background Color

Tags: html, css

I created a little site tonight about watches. You can visit it at horology dot info.

(Please do not post the actual URL of my site in your response.)

I was wondering why the dropdown menu -- which I got from https://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/ -- appears in id="content" rather than id="banner" (with the blue background). I want the menu to appear underneath the logo text with the blue background. Additionally, does anyone know why there is a lot of vertical space before the banner? I also want less empty vertical space at the top. By the way, I am using Firefox on Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add display property (display: inline-block;) to your #banner class in "/horology.css"

```css
#banner {
    width: 800px;
    background-color: #00C;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it! I also adjusted the space above the logo text by adding "line-height: 0" to .logo. Do you know how to decrease the amount of vertical space even more?

Comment: your title Horology has a class 'logo' which added a margin of 1em... you can try reducing it to get your required impact